# Displaying 3D model in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, 3d, expo

In current project i need t display 3D model (.obj and its texture .png) in react native EXPO. I need to load model in View just to diplay it there for beginning.
 I tried with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-3d-model-view) but no luck. Does anyone know how to do this.

Comment: You’re probably going to have to `eject` from Expo if you want to do something like that.

Comment: There is expo-three. Is ti fit for your purpose?