# React native expo. How to render a .glb 3D Model from an URL?

Tags: javascript, react-native, 3d, expo

I come from web develop using React and for 3D, the [<model-viewer>](https://modelviewer.dev/) package.
I'm working now with react native expo and I have worked for this project since a year. 
Now I'm trying to implement the visualization of 3D, using the [expo-three](https://github.com/expo/expo-three) package. Because, it's difficult to understand the doc, I was trying to search an example, but I did't find anything useful. 
I tried to search in SO, but the only similar question I found:

- [haven't a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72153202/how-to-render-custom-3d-object-in-react-native)
- or an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74240113/how-to-import-the-3d-model-into-my-react-native-expo-app)
- or [they use a different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311954/cant-load-obj-model-with-textures-using-expo-three)
- or [are not reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705272/loading-glb-model-in-react-native-three-using-expo-three-component-not-working-o)
- or [are without expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584057/is-there-a-way-to-display-3d-models-in-a-react-native-project-without-expo)
- or [are examples without file rendering](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-demo-rrppl0y8l4)
- or are just react and not react native solutions

In other places [are full native](https://reactnativeexample.com/a-react-native-view-for-displaying-3d-models/), but I can't use this command `react-native link react-native-3d-model-view` because I'm using expo and I don't want to code deep native.

Therefore. I'm asking for a full .js file (not code pieces) example only using react native expo packages like three, expo-three, and expo-gl for rendering a .glb 3D model from a url in a react native app. I have spent a lot of time trying to achieve this. **I will be very grateful for this!**
[Here is an example url for a .glb file](https://universobucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Test/Scout+Trooper+-+Lego.glb)

I know that it is posible because of an [outdate solution's issue in GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo-three/issues/166). Answering to the solution of eject expo in this [question's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069189/displaying-3d-model-in-react-native-expo)

I have successfully render a blue rotating cube but not a file:

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import {
  Scene,
  Mesh,
  MeshBasicMaterial,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  BoxBufferGeometry,
} from "three";
import { Renderer } from "expo-three";
import { GLView } from "expo-gl";

const App = () => {
  const onContextCreate = async (gl) => {
    // three.js implementation.
    const scene = new Scene();
    const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      gl.drawingBufferWidth / gl.drawingBufferHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );
    gl.canvas = {
      width: gl.drawingBufferWidth,
      height: gl.drawingBufferHeight,
    };

    // set camera position away from cube
    camera.position.z = 2;

    const renderer = new Renderer({ gl });
    // set size of buffer to be equal to drawing buffer width
    renderer.setSize(gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

    // create cube
    // define geometry
    const geometry = new BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: "cyan",
    });

    const cube = new Mesh(geometry, material);

    // add cube to scene
    scene.add(cube);

    // create render function
    const render = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      // create rotate functionality
      // rotate around x axis
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;

      // rotate around y axis
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      gl.endFrameEXP();
    };

    // call render
    render();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <GLView
        onContextCreate={onContextCreate}
        // set height and width of GLView
        style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If you read this, [upvote the change in expo](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/easy-implementation-of-3d-model-view)

Comment: did you publish in github? could you publish it?